# Can there be multiple Cartesian equations of a plane?

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to find the Cartesian equation of this plane given in the parametric form:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
x-1&=-s+t\\
y-2&=-s-3t\\
z&=s-3t
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

Which is equivalent to

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
x-1&=-s+t\\
-x+y-1&=-4t\\
x+z-1&=-2t
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

Now, from here, I'm tempted to multiply the second equation by $-2$ and subtract this from the third equation. This would give me:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
x-1&=-s+t\\
-x+y-1&=-4t\\
3x-2y+z+1&=0
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

However, the answer key gives me:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
x-1&=-s+t\\
-x+y-1&=-4t\\
3x-y+2z-1&=0
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

Which I believe comes from multiplying the third equation by $2$ and subtracting the second equation from that.

My question is, are both

$$
3x-2y+z=-1
$$
and 
$$
3x-y+2z=1
$$

correct as the Cartesian equation of the plane?

Comment: Both equations define different planes because one has normal vector $(3,-2,1)$, and the other one has $(3,-1,2)$ and these are not multiples of each other.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: are you sure ???

Comment: Yes! I am sure. See my post.

Comment: How does that make sense from a geometric perspective? I have one plane given but end up with two different ones?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: was the question changed since you answered ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust I just did not see the second equation! You can see it in my post before my fixing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check:**

$$3(-s+t+1)-2(-s-3t+2)+(s-3t)=\color{red}{6t-1}$$

and

$$3(-s+t+1)-(-s-3t+2)+2(s-3t)=1.$$

Comment: Ah, I see what you're getting at. My second one is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

In your second system: $$(2)\qquad \begin{cases}x-1=-s+t\\-x+y-1=-4t\\x+z-1=-2t\end{cases}$$
performing the operation you describe does not give you the third equation in your third system: $$(3)\qquad \begin{cases}x-1=-s+t\\-x+y-1=-4t\\\color{red}{3x-2y+z+1=0}\end{cases}$$
What you could do is subtract the second equation from $2$ times the third equation to get: $$(3')\qquad \begin{cases}x-1=-s+t\\-x+y-1=-4t\\\color{blue}{3x-y+2z-1=0}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks, I was suspecting I did something stupid. I guess the question still stands though since people are commenting as if my question made sense.

Comment: @Chisq Well those two planes are certainly different. The red one has normal vector $(3,-2,1)$ whereas the other has $(3,-1,2)$. Only the blue one is correct.

Comment: Yea I see what people are saying now. This question can be taken down now if this website allows that.

Comment: @Chisq there's no need to take down the question.

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake in your computations. If you do what you wrote, you cannot possibly get $0$ after the $=$ sign. Instead, you should do:$$-(-x+y-1=-4t)+2(x+z-1=-2t)=3x-y+2z-1=0.$$